# Выбрать значения из select чтобы они не совпадали

Tags: jmeter

Есть два одинаковых селекта как выбрать рандомно уникальные значения?

```
    <select name="cars1" >
<option selected="selected" value="Posrhe">Posrhe</option>
<option value="Lada">Lada</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <select name="cars2" >
<option selected="selected" value="Posrhe">Posrhe</option>
<option value="Lada">Lada</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
```

Сделал вот так но в какой то момент значения могут совпасть

```
<option value="(.+?)">(.+?)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавьте первый [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) к тому элементу, который возвращает ваш селект и сконфигурируйте его примерно так:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   он вытащит рандомную машинку из первого селекта и запишет значение в [переменную](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `car1`

   На всякий случай XPath в виде текста: `//select[@name='cars1']/option/@value`
2. Добавьте второй XPath Extractor ниже первого и используйте следующую конфигурацию

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   и опять XPath в виде текста: `//select[@name='cars2']/option[not(@value='${car1}')]/@value`
3. Используйте `${car1}` и `${car2}` где нужно

Если сервер возвращает валидный XML/HTML - лучше использовать [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations), он мощнее и быстрее работает.